# Problems overriding default template in Magento V-1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, page-layouts

Pretty basic thing I am doing , and I am reasonably new to Magento theming.

I want a `1column layout` as the default layout for the home page , and I have copied the base 1column.phtml to `app\design\frontend\[mytheme]\default\template\page\`  and modified accordingly.

My `local.xml` file starts like the code below ( and there are no duplicate sections or anything ).

Everything else I do in the `local.xml` file, does what it should ( add CSS , JS  , remove poll etc ) .

When I put the template hint on - it shows me that it is using

`frontend/[mytheme]/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml`  - which is a valid file but I want it to use the 1column file.

Everything else is standard - and I am only using local.xml to override theme changes - nothing else.

Help!  Thanks - appreciate your time.

```
    <reference name="root">
        <!-- define the default template for the theme -->
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  the home page is setting the template layout in CMS and is obviously overriding the default.